# bridge fdb show entry is not showed

Tags: networking, kernel

show all entries， I found `00:1c:c2:35:8a:f3` on eth0.1 is missed

```
# ./bridge fdb | grep eth0.1
d4:3a:65:08:db:96 dev eth0.1 master br-lan
01:00:5e:00:00:01 dev eth0.1 self permanent
01:80:c2:00:00:0e dev eth0.1 self permanent
01:80:c2:00:00:03 dev eth0.1 self permanent
01:80:c2:00:00:00 dev eth0.1 self permanent
```

but if i filter by brport. `00:1c:c2:35:8a:f3` is showed

```
# ./bridge fdb show brport eth0.1
00:1c:c2:35:8a:f3 master br-lan
d4:3a:65:08:db:96 master br-lan
01:00:5e:00:00:01 self permanent
01:80:c2:00:00:0e self permanent
01:80:c2:00:00:03 self permanent
01:80:c2:00:00:00 self permanent
```

brctl showmacs also show

```
# brctl showmacs br-lan
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
 12     00:1c:c2:35:8a:f3       no                 0.70
  3     30:00:00:12:00:02       no                 1.71
  4     4c:c6:4c:61:41:fc       yes                0.00
  5     4c:c6:4c:61:41:fd       yes                0.00
  1     4c:c6:4c:61:41:fe       yes                0.00
  7     52:c6:4c:61:41:fd       yes                0.00
  6     52:c6:4c:61:41:fe       yes                0.00
 10     56:c6:4c:61:41:fd       yes                0.00
  8     5a:c6:4c:61:41:fd       yes                0.00
 11     5a:c6:4c:61:41:fe       yes                0.00
  5     62:ab:b3:6c:b3:6d       no                 5.42
  3     9c:7b:ef:45:a5:82       no                33.09
 12     d4:3a:65:08:db:96       no                 0.90
```

is this a bug in kernel ?